# unity crashes when script runs

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, udp, unityscript

in my simple usp server finder script when i select client it makes unity crash and i can't find why;

```
import System.Net.Sockets;

private var udp_server:UdpClient;
private var udp_client:UdpClient;
private var udp_port:int = 18000;
private var udp_broadcast_ip:IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse ("224.0.0.224");

private var udp_received_message:String;
private var udp_endpoint:IPEndPoint;

private var selected:boolean = false;
private var clientStarted:boolean = false;

function StartServer(){

    udp_server = new UdpClient(udp_port, AddressFamily.InterNetwork);

    udp_server.JoinMulticastGroup(udp_broadcast_ip);
    udp_endpoint = new IPEndPoint(udp_broadcast_ip, udp_port);

    InvokeRepeating("StartBroadcastUDP", 0.0,0.3);
}

function StartClient(){
    udp_client = new UdpClient();

    udp_endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, udp_port);
    udp_client.Client.Bind(udp_endpoint);

    udp_client.JoinMulticastGroup(udp_broadcast_ip);

    /*
    while(true){
        yield;
        var udp_received_message_byte:byte[] = udp_client.Receive(udp_endpoint);
        udp_received_message = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(udp_received_message_byte);
        print("Received Message: " + udp_received_message);
    }*/

    clientStarted = true;

}

function StartBroadcastUDP(){
    var udp_broadcast_message = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("GAME SERVER");

    if(udp_broadcast_message != ""){

        udp_server.Send(udp_broadcast_message, udp_broadcast_message.Length);
    }
}

function OnGUI(){
    if(!selected){
        if(GUI.Button(Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), "Server")){
            StartServer();
            selected = true;
        }else if(GUI.Button(Rect(100, 0, 100, 100), "Client")){
            StartClient();
            selected = true;
        }
    }
}

function Update(){
    /*
    if(clientStarted){
        var udp_received_message_byte:byte[] = udp_client.Receive(udp_endpoint);
        udp_received_message = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(udp_received_message_byte);
        print("Received Message: " + udp_received_message);
    }*/
}
```

in both of the commented parts i tried doing this, in the first i used while to keep it in the same function but it crashed so i mmoved it into the update function but it still crashes. help?

Comment: If the commented out code is not necessary to reproduce the bug, why post it at all? It would be easier to locate the problem if you only left the minimal amount of code that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also, what does "crashes" mean, exactly?

Comment: the comment code is what makes the crash; when i uncomment the while loop in StartClient function it crashes so at first i though it was the while loop that made it crash so i commented it and wrote it again in the update function so when i say that clientstarted is true in startclient() the update function will run the code but that makes it crash also, so i can't realy guess what makes it crash (when i mean crash i mean in windows make the editor not respond and eventually close itself and on android just close the app). also if it helps here is the log file - http://pastebin.com/JZ1kY62a

Answer (score 0):

The `while(true)`in `StartClient()` will indeed make the editor / app to be frozen, because  `StartClient()` is not called as a Coroutine, so yield does not return to the Unity engine, and your program is stuck forever in the while.

There is another thing thus. It looks like `udp-client.Receive` is a synchronous call, meaning it's blocking the code waiting for a packet. The game will indeed freeze unless you have like 60 packets per seconds.